# How do I run Atom in Ubuntu WSL?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, atom-editor

I am trying to run Atom editor in ubuntu.

I installed ubuntu then node.js. Both seem to work fine. Then I followed the instructions on this site for installing Atom: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-atom-text-editor-on-ubuntu-20-04/

My version of ubuntu is 20.04

When I then type "atom" in ubuntu I get the following:

```
ro@PC:~$ atom
expr: syntax error: missing argument after ‘8’
ro@PC:~$ /usr/bin/atom: line 195:    89 Segmentation fault      nohup "$ATOM_PATH" --executed-from="$(pwd)" --pid=$$ "$@" > "$ATOM_HOME/nohup.out" 2>&1
```

This is what is in my .atom folder:

```
ro@PC:~/.atom$ ll
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 ro ro 4096 Apr 25 09:52 ./
drwxr-xr-x 9 ro ro 4096 Apr 25 09:52 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 ro ro    0 Apr 25 11:52 nohup.out
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong as I am new to linux

Assistance would be appreciated Thank you

Comment: I see this was closed as "Needs details", which it really doesn't since I can reproduce it myself.  Could you repost this over on our sister site [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) where I can try to answer it for you (since I can't here now that it's closed).  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds ok, thank you. I posted on Ask Ubuntu as you suggested: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404675/how-do-i-run-atom-and-ubuntu-wsl-i-am-getting-an-error